# Is it possible to have an option value set to "false" when not checked, for emailing purposes?

Tags: html, email

So I didn't know how to phrase the question so I'll try to explain better here.

I'm creating a form for submitting a quote estimate, using Formspree. This is some of my code:

```
Search Engine Optimisation
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="seo" name="seo" value="true">
</label>

Social Media Integration
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="social" name="social" value="true">
</label>
```

But if the user doesn't check a box, I won't receive that particular option via email. But it would be nice to say "no" or "false" if it is left unchecked. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is way using a hidden input

Basically, having a hidden input before your actual checkbox with both input sharing the same name. It mean that if the value of the checkbox is not selected, it will send the hidden input instead.

So in your example :

```
Search Engine Optimisation
 <label>
  <input type="hidden" name="seo" value="false">
  <input type="checkbox" id="seo" name="seo" value="true">
</label>

Social Media Integration
<label>
  <input type="hidden" name="social" value="false">
  <input type="checkbox" id="social" name="social" value="true">
</label>
```

To be more precise,  both value will be sent but your backend will take the last value (e.g PHP)

Comment: that will send &seo=false&seo=true - so your backend needs to sort it out if there is one or two values - or will php take whatever is last?

Comment: PHP, ruby and node.js will take the last value when facing duplicate.

Comment: I did not know what Formspree was, just saw that it had "no  backend", did not expect that. I will check if I find something

Comment: Did you get any info regarding if this is solved automatically by Formspree?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure to send only one field, then this will work too.

The form will only send the named field

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
   document.getElementById("seo").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
     const tgt = e.target;
     document.querySelector("[name="+tgt.id+"]").value=tgt.value;
   })  
})
```

```html
Search Engine Optimisation
<label>
    <input type="hidden" name="seo" value="false">
    <input type="checkbox" id="seo" value="true">
</label>
```